# How to add quantities with duplicate keys

Tags: numbers, key, duplicates, addition

### Data :

(Boss, Count_DR)
(B1,30),
(B2,20),
(B1,40),
(B3,50)

How to store in java collections or how to print in the following format?
Duplicates have to be added So B1(30+40)
(B1,70),
(B2,20),
(B3,50)

In SQL I can simply do it as 
select Boss, sum(Count_DR) from table 
Group By Boss;

I am just finding simplest way of doing it in Java. Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: output expected:(B1,70), (B2,20), (B3,50)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do Java, but
Create a hashmap to hold the key value pairs
loop through the input pairs

if the key is present in the hash sum the current value plus the input
if the key isn't present add it and the value to the hash.